# Window corners don't render properly

Tags: macos, mac, bug, ui

I have recently noticed that some of my windows have weird looking corners. It's like they are missing dark pixels right on the edge.

[image: weird corners]

It doesn't always happen, some windows seem to be 'immune' - one example would be Messages, which is the window in the middle.

I'm running OS X 10.9.3.

Comment: Do other users on the same computer have the same issue? (I can't reproduce this behaviour on my machine.)

Comment: I'm the only user on this computer, but I've just tried enabling the guest account, and it still looks this way when I'm logged in as a guest.

Comment: Is this a MBP? If so, is it a Retina display MBP? 

Judging by the picture in the OP, it seems that it only happens when multiple windows are open at the same time, is this an accurate assumption?

Comment: Nope, it's Air (13-inch, Early 2014).

Comment: @smadeja I'm not familiar with that model's internal specs. Do you mind providing us with the specs - especially the graphics information?

Comment: Sure. It's a 1.4 Ghz Intel Core i5 with HD Graphics 5000. The problem seems inconsistent, at the moment all inactive windows look fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure, but it seems to be caused by Firefox. If Finder and Terminal are the first windows to be opened after booting the system, they look fine. If I begin by starting Firefox instead, windows opened afterwards become corrupted.

Answer (score 0):

After [the OS X Mavericks v10.9.4 Update](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT6281), window corners have returned to their previous glory. Update notes don't mention any issue of this kind, so I guess it might have been fixed as a side effect of running the system updater.

EDIT: Aaand the corners are ugly again. It's really weird.